# sending textfield data to servlet in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, servlets, extjs, extjs4.1

I want send a text field data to a servlet page. I dont know the process. I give the code for textbox and a button below.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
var movie_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
    renderTo: document.body,
    frame: true,
    title: 'Personal Information Form',
    width: 250,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Firstname',
        name: 'firstname',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        xtype:'button',
        text:'save'    
    }]
});
```

});

This is the code ofr a textbox and a button. when i click the button the data of the field will go to a servlet page. But I cant do that. Please any one help me. the name of the servlet page is url_servlet

Answer (score 1):

in your service method (get or post )

you can get your data field values by the attribute "name".

```
  String firstname = reg.getParameter("firstname");
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling the data in the backend check @The Suresh Atta's answer.

I found some errata in your code:

1) Construct an Ext component with the Ext.create function.
2) Use Ext.getBody() to get the document body.
3) Put your fields in the items config and buttons in the buttons config (Not always the best practice).

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    frame: true,
    title: 'Personal Information Form',
    width: 250,
    url: 'url_servlet',// The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Firstname',
        name: 'firstname',
        allowBlank: false
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    success: function(form, action) {
                       Console.log('Success', action.result.msg);
                    },
                    failure: function(form, action) {
                       Console.log('Failed', action.result.msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

I hope this helps you a bit ;)